# How to do Mercurial's 'hg remove' for all missing files?

Tags: mercurial

I use this to remove a file from the repo:

```
hg remove <full file path>
```

What command can you use to do an `hg remove` on *all* files that have been deleted locally?

By deleted locally, I mean those showing up with an `!` when you do `hg status`.

For adds, you can just do `hg add` to add all new files (those prefixed with `?`).

Answer (score 377, accepted):

This will add all new files that are not ignored, and remove all locally missing files

```
hg addremove
```

Either of these will remove all locally missing files(They are the same command)

```
hg remove --after
hg remove -A
```

Comment: there is also hg forget which is eqivalent to hg rm -Af

Comment: the jk for a username is menacing, i feel like evertime i read one of your comments or posts you are saying "just kidding" at the end :( that being said, this helped, cheers!

Comment: one word of warning... don't freak out when it dumps a whole bunch of crap to the screen... (like I did)

Comment: Wow!  Thanks!  That helped a lot!  Wow!  +1 :)  `hg rm -A`

Comment: So `hg remove` takes `-A` for all, but `hg add` doesn't?

Answer (score 35):

If you intend to do addremove and commit, it can be joined with '-A' option as shown [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html):

```
hg commit -A -m 'Commit with addremove'
```

Comment: Phew! This saved me a whole bunch of time, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The original question asked how to remove (i.e. forget) files that show up as `"!"` when using `hg st`.  A direct approach which has the advantage of transparency is to use `hg st` with the `-n` option:

```
hg -v forget $(hg st -nd)
```

(Of course the files will only be forgotten at the next *commit*.)

The flags are well-documented elsewhere (e.g. by the hg command itself), but in brief:

- `-n` means "filename only"
- `-d` means "select files that have been deleted"

Comment: Can you explain each of those flags?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to addremove and commit, but are not ready to commit the rest of your changes, I think you still have to enumerate them:

```
$ hg st
M modified-file
A added-file
R removed-file-1
R removed-file-2

$ hg commit -m"remove removed-file-1 and removed-file-2" removed-file-*
abort: removed-file-*: No such file or directory

$ hg commit -m"remove removed-file-1 and removed-file-2" removed-file-1 removed-file-2
committed changeset 185:628800a7af84
```