# How to forget all removed files with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am new to Mercurial and after a cleanup of the image folder in my project, I have a ton of files showing with ! in the 'hg status'. I can type a 'hg forget ' for each, but there must be an easier way.

So how can I tell mercurial to forget about all the removed (status = !) files in a folder?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412239/how-to-do-mercurials-hg-remove-for-all-missing-files

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, though solving either one requires listing files that don't show up in `ls`.  That question asks how to mark deleted files as hg removed.  This one is how to *un*mark all the hg removed files.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're also okay with adding any files that exist and aren't ignored then:

```
hg addremove
```

would a popular way to do that.

Comment: True, adding  untracked files and marking missing files as removed in one shorthand command. +1

Comment: This works for recursive folder traversal too, where-as the forget -I has to be performed in the directory of the files to be removed.

Answer (score 10):

With fileset (Mercurial 1.9):

```
hg forget "set:deleted()"
```

In general, on Linux or Mac:

```
hg status -dn | while read file ; do hg forget "$file" ; done
```

Or, if your shell allows it, if there are not too many files, and if the filenames do not contain spaces or special characters, then:

```
hg forget $(hg st -dn)
```

I

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
hg forget -I '*'
```

in order to include all files in your forget command.

Comment: be careful, that won't catch files beginning with a dot in the current directory.

Comment: didn't do anything for me: "abort: no files specified"

Comment: Would you need \*\* instead of * in order to look beyond the root directory?  (`hg help patterns`)

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Six years later, I would suppose so, but I don't have a mercurial to test right now.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `-d` flag for status, which displays missing files:

`for file in $(hg status -d | cut -d " " -f 2); do echo hg forget $file; done`

Run this in the root of your repo, and if you're happy with the results, remove the `echo`

This has the bonus over the accepted answer of **not** doing any additional work, e.g. adding a bunch of untracked files.

Comment: I get `no such file or directory` for each of the files, probably they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

more shorter instead of

```
for file in $(hg status -d | cut -d " " -f 2); do echo hg forget $file; done
```

this

```
hg status -d | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs echo hg forget # test case
hg status -d | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs hg forget # real work
```