# Remove all deleted files in next commit with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Let's say I have the current `status`:

```
M File1.cs
M File2.cs
M File3.cs
! File4.cs
! File5.cs
! File6.cs
```

How do I bulk `remove` files 4, 5, 6 (`!`) from the next commit?

At the moment, I am just removing them manually before committing, like such:

```
hg remove File4.cs
hg remove File5.cs
hg remove File6.cs
```

But is there a way to remove them all at one go ?

Comment: duplicate of [How to do Mercurial's 'hg remove' for all missing files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412239/how-to-do-mercurials-hg-remove-for-all-missing-files)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Run `hg addremove`

Comment: `remove --after` is probably better (doesn't add files)

Comment: good point.  I voted for close on the dupe, but you should add that answer anyway.

Answer (score 27):

```
hg remove --after
```

...is probably better (doesn't add files)

This is taken straight from the comment by tonfa in the accepted answer.  I'm adding it because it was never added as a separate Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or just

```
hg addr
```

:)
it is shortcut from

```
hg addremove
```

Answer (score 0):

try the hg help system

```
hg help
```

and you will get the command in the beginning:

```
list of commands:
  add           add the specified files on the next commit
  addremove     add all new files, delete all missing files
  ...
```

so you can use

```
hg addremove
```